# My home page is not open DNS error appear

Tags: wordpress, dns

> HI!! How are you ... i am fine but i am worried about my home page i
>   am newly create web page but its not show on my browser and its shows
>   DNS error can you help me how to resolve this problem [Web Page](http://whatsappstatusline.com/) .Thanks If any
>   so please help me my Homepage Url is given below . my freind tell me
>   its on pc settings but i searched i can not find .my home page is 
>   [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e496B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change your dns to google dns.
use following.

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4.
```